# How to tell if more than one MongoDB is installed on Windows

Tags: database, mongodb, windows

I have a strange problem with MongoDB. When I run `mongod` mongo appears to start up without any issues.
However, all my collections are empty.

This happened once before and, not able to find the solution, I assumed that my data had just somehow been deleted. Then it suddenly reappeared a few weeks later and I am not sure why.

The only thing I can think of is the possibility that two versions are somehow installed and one is totally empty. That said, I cannot find another `mongod`.

This is the path I am currently using to start Mongo.

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin>`

I have checked the data folder and there appear to be collections in it, with a total size of over 500Mb.

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\data`

How might I be able to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: if  you do not specify explicitely where the data is located , the defaut location in windows is c:\data\db

Comment: You may install MongoDB as a service (see [mongod.exe](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/program/mongod.exe/)) and use a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/configuration-options/)